# How to find a set numeric value from a list of numbers which can be repeated?

Tags: algorithm

I am new to Java and I need to write an algorithm to find sets of numbers that match a given total from a list of numbers.

You are given a number you need to reach from a list of numbers.

Sum Total: 10

List: 3 6 7 5 2 8 4

You are also told how many numbers must be used in the Sum.

Count: 3

The result needs to include repeats of the same number in the list like the following:

Results:

3+3+4=10

3+5+3=10

4+4+2=10

The Total, List & Count values can change so the algorithm needs to allow for variants in values.

Limits:
There can be a Maximum of 100 integers in the list.
Numbers in the list can vary from 1 to 100.
Maximum Total Sum is 1000
Maximum Count is 25
All integers are positive values.

The following code works, but does not cater for repeating in the numbers;

```
N = 10;
M = 3;
Input = "7 3 6 7 5 2 8 4";
String[] items = Input.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < items.length; j++) {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < items.length; k++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(items[i]) + Integer.parseInt(items[j]) + Integer.parseInt(items[k]) == N) {
            System.out.println(items[i] + " + " + items[j] + " + " + items[k] +" = " + N);
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Thanks in advance for any help,

Darren

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you want to generate all [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) with a certain number of parts and a limited set of choices for each part. Okay, but: the number of partitions of 1000 into 25 parts bounded by 100 is ~6.88e22 (69 sextillion). Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: Lets put this in a product related issue so it may become more clearer..
The objective is to write a program that works out the number of combinations available for someone to select a box of chocolates.
There can be anything from 1-100 chocolate types and each chocolate has a value (list of numbers, each number is a chocolate and its value.
The Sum total is the Price of the chocolate box which can be up to 1000.

Comment: The user also has the option to select how many chocolates are in the box which is the Count figure.